# What is the function to get the object of a NXT asset in javascript?

Tags: nxt

I want to get an object and its variables of a NXT asset. What is the function to retrieve an object of an nxt asset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get most of the nxt objects using NRS.sendRequest(""

The following code gets the asset object of whats in question.

**NRS.sendRequest("getAsset", {"asset": asset}, function(response) { //do stuff with response}, false)**

```
NRS.sendRequest("getAsset", {   
  "asset": <*Your Asset ID here*>
}, function(response) {         
  if (response && response.asset) {
    console.log(response);        
  }, false                          
});
```

You would get the following response from chrome's console log like this:

http://prntscr.com/7zm5fh

[image]